# how do I install a Canon Pixma Pro-100 printer on Ubuntu version 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: wireless, printing, ethernet

So far I cannot get Ubuntu even to see it by way of WiFi. I'm ready to try hard-wire (Ethernet).
Any suggestion or solution getting this to work, I would be so thankful, Thanks ahead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.
  
You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.
  
From the command line, 

`lpstat -t`
  
will show the total state of the printing system.